# Implement formula in a column based on contents of each cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In my Google Sheet, I have 1000+ rows of Date entries. For each Date, I am calculating the Month# and Week# using MONTH() and WEEKDAY() functions respectively.
Here is the link to a **sample file**: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Af5-pYMFWZ1QtLoaAbPZYMGRvk43JBslUp4KyOFADfA/edit?usp=sharing

**Problem Statement**:
For all rows which have a unique Month# and Week#, I would like to implement a formula and calculate Output. For example, in my sheet, rows 3 to 6 pertain to Month=1 and Week=4. For this set of 5 rows I am calculating Output column as the subtraction from the first element in that set (ie... C3-$C$3, C4-$C$3, C5-$C$3 so on ). Similarly row 7 to 10 pertain to Month=1 and Week=5, and so I calculate Output
as Data-$C$7 and so on.

How do I implement this structure to calculate Output column on each set of unique Month# and Week# values?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete everything from Column F (including the F2 header). Then place the following formula into cell F2:

`=ArrayFormula({"Output";IF(C3:C="",,IFERROR(C3:C-VLOOKUP(E3:E,{E3:E,C3:C},2,FALSE)))})`

This one formula will create the header and return results for all valid rows.

Since `VLOOKUP` always finds *only the first* matching instance of what it is looking up, we can use it to ask that each value in C3:C subtract that first instance of where week-number match for each row.

By the way, although you didn't ask about this, you can also use this type of array formula in Columns D and E, instead of all of the individual formulas you have. To do that, delete everything from Columns D and E (including the headers). Then...

Place the following formula in D2:

`=ArrayFormula({"Month #";IF(B3:B="",,MONTH(B3:B))})`

... and the following formula in E2:

`=ArrayFormula({"Week #";IF(B3:B="",,WEEKNUM(B3:B))})`

Comment: Your code certainly works, thank you! I must confess, I am still a bit dazed about how you are using the VLOOKUP, especially the expression {D3:D&"~"&E3:E,C3:C} . What is the function of ~ as well as & ? Nxt problem is: I need to have another column calculates the MAX value for each set. The trick is that my data is a time series. So for row3, the value wud be 54.32. For row4 it be MAX(54.32, 54.93), row 5 will be MAX (54.32, 54.93, 54.34) , row6 be MAX (54.32, 54.93, 54.34 , 52.7). However, for row8, we enter new set (Month=1,Week=5) so row7 will be 52.51 and so on.. Any suggestions?

Comment: Following is the Gsheet link where I have indicated a column "RunningMax" demonstrating the formula: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Af5-pYMFWZ1QtLoaAbPZYMGRvk43JBslUp4KyOFADfA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The ampersand (`&`) is just shorthand concatenation; and the tilde (`~`)is just used as a separation between the numbers so that they don't run together in the `VLOOKUP` matching (e.g., otherwise 114 could have been 1&14 or 11&4, but will now be 1~14 or 11~4). As for your additional request(s), per Stack guidelines and its intended purpose of being a searchable database for future site visitors, please post a *new post* for each separate issue. This also allows the wider volunteer community to offer help rather than one volunteer.

Comment: Yes sure, makes sense. Here is the new post I created just now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71898617/google-sheet-calculate-the-running-max-of-data-for-each-set-or-rows-identifie

Comment: In actuality, now that I look at this again, because both the month and week are always moving upward, you don't actually need to include the month at all. I've modified the formula in the post to reflect this. However, be careful: if you are going to go past one year with any formula that will rely on these dates, you'll *need* to include the year in all such formulas. Otherwise, there will be no way to distinguish month numbers or week numbers between one year and the next/last.

Comment: Understood, thank you for your input!