# Calculate the "running max" of data for each set of rows identified by some particular values in another cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Please see attached photo.

On Google sheet, I want that rows with a particular Month and Week combination be treated as a separate set. Within each of such set, I would like to implement a formula to calculate a 'running Max' of data in column C (I have shown the formula implementation in column J for your understanding).
How do I realize the "Running Max" column as indicated?

Here is the link to the Google Sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Af5-pYMFWZ1QtLoaAbPZYMGRvk43JBslUp4KyOFADfA/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try for MAX

```
=ArrayFormula(transpose(query(
if(row(C3:C)>transpose(row(C3:C)),,C3:C)*(transpose(E3:E)=E3:E)*(transpose(D3:D)=D3:D),
"select " & join(",","max(Col" & sequence(1, count(C3:C)) & ")") &
"label "  & join(",","max(Col" & sequence(1, count(C3:C)) & ") ''") & "" )))
```

[image]

for MIN

```
=ArrayFormula(transpose(query(
if(row(C3:C)>transpose(row(C3:C)),9^9,C3:C)*(if(transpose(E3:E)=E3:E,1,9^9))*(if(transpose(D3:D)=D3:D,1,9^9)),
"select " & join(",","min(Col" & sequence(1, count(C3:C)) & ")") & "label "  & join(",","min(Col" & sequence(1, count(C3:C)) & ") ''") & "" )))
```

[image]

Comment: this code works, thank you! A follow up question- if instead of finding the MAX, if I were to find the MIN instead, would this suggested code work if I simply replace 'max' by 'min'? I tried but it shows all 0. I am still in process to understand your code (transpose, select, label are new functions for me in Gsheet), Do chime in.

Comment: see updated proposal

Comment: Thank you! there is quite much for me to learn here, thanks for sharing

Comment: What is the use of 9^9 in the MIN code? Is it denoting putting a very large number for some purpose?

Comment: to give a very high value instead of 0 when the conditions are not met (that's why when we don't give 9^9 the result will be 0 for the min calculation)

Comment: when I use the formula on a larger data set with 500+ rows, the sheet hangs up and crashes. So was thinking if there is anything I could do to overcome this

Comment: if you need such a large number of rows, the array formula is not suitable here because it uses a large square of 500x500 cells! you can then divide the formula by several sets of 100 rows for example. Cut to an appropriate criteria change for you.

Comment: You can do this with a pivot table, but in this case which is much lighter, you won't be able to get the running value in a week, just the min and max value for each week. If that way convenient for you? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i56jDzWGhNFzmgeO4a3ANVJQNz6IZjNLppi-C7pZmxo/copy

Comment: no I need the 'running' max and min within each week and so I guess your pivot table implementation would not work. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: So I think that the only way is to cut your data so that each set will not exceed 100 or 200 rows and apply the arrayformula on each set of rows. In that case, don't forget to limit the area as follows (for instance) `=ArrayFormula(transpose(query(
if(row(C3:C99)>transpose(row(C3:C99)),,C3:C99)*(transpose(E3:E99)=E3:E99)*(transpose(D3:D99)=D3:D99),
"select " & join(",","max(Col" & sequence(1, count(C3:C99)) & ")") &
"label "  & join(",","max(Col" & sequence(1, count(C3:C99)) & ") ''") & "" )))`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the formulas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70578695/running-max-arrayformula-for-google-sheets)

Mine can be tweaked very easily to answer your question:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(C3:C="",,vlookup(row(C3:C),
{if(countifs(C3:C,">"&C3:C,row(C3:C),"<"&row(C3:C),E3:E,E3:E)=0,row(C3:C)),C3:C}
,2)))
```

It's OK for moderate amounts of data but as you can see from the link the accepted answer is better for large amounts of data. I don't know how you would adapt it though.

[image]

```
=ArrayFormula(if(C3:C="",,vlookup(row(C3:C),
{if(countifs(C3:C,"<"&C3:C,row(C3:C),"<"&row(C3:C),E3:E,E3:E)=0,row(C3:C)),C3:C}
,2)))
```

for minimum.